# What is the difference between Feedforward Neural Networks (ANN) and Recurrent Neural Networks (RNN)

Tags: neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

In ANN the equation during Forward Propagation is `Y = W.X + b`.

What is the equation during Forward Propagation for RNN, as it involves `States` and `Timesteps`.

What is the difference between `ANN` and `RNN` in terms of Back Propagation.

Also, what is the difference in functionality between `Dropout` in ANN vs `Recurrent_Dropout` in RNN.

Are there any other key differences between `ANN` and `RNN`.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about programming. I think you will have more success receiving an appropriate answer by asking on the right platform, e.g. at https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation for Forward Propagation of RNN, considering `Two Timesteps`, in a simple form, is shown below:

**Output of the First Time Step**: `Y0 = (Wx * X0) + b)`

**Output of the Second Time Step**: `Y1 = (Wx * X1) + Y0 * Wy + b` where `Y0 = (Wx * X0) + b)`

To elaborate it, consider `RNN` has 5 `Neurons/Units`, more detailed equation is mentioned in the screenshot below:

[Equation of Forward Propagation of RNN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNnjU.png)

**Back Propagation in RNN**:

- The Back Propagation in RNN is done through each and every Timestep. Hence it is called Backpropagation through Time (BPTT).
- The output sequence is evaluated using a `cost` function `C(y(t(min)), y(t(min+1)), ... y(t(max)))` (where `tmin` and `tmax` are the first and last output time steps, not counting the ignored outputs), and the gradients of that cost function are propagated backward through the unrolled network
- Finally the model parameters are updated using the gradients, computed during BPTT
- Note that the gradients flow backward through all the outputs used by the cost function, not just through the final output

In the screenshot below, Dashed Lines represents `Forward Propagation` and Solid Lines represents `Back Propagation`.

[Flow of Forward Propagation and Back Propagation in RNN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdhll.png)

**Dropout**: If we set the value of `Dropout` as `0.1` in a `Recurrent Layer` (LSTM), it means that it will pass only 90% of Inputs to the Recurrent Layer

**Recurrent Droput** If we set the value of `Recurrent Dropout` as `0.2` in a `Recurrent Layer` (LSTM), it means that it will consider only 80% of the Time Steps for that Recurrent Layer

Hope this answers all your queries!